# Returning multiple values based on search criteria

Tags: excel

I have multiple states listed in column A and each have many corresponding values in column B. The same state is listed for each value in column B. Example: Rows 2 through 5 in Column A will have California with Rows 2 through 5 in Column B having Item 1, Item 2, Item 3 and Item 4.

*The source data will be hidden from the end user so that they will only have to input the search criteria.*

Without using VBA (this will be touched by too many people to make VBA feasible), I am trying to come up with an array formula but have never used one before. I want to be able to input search criteria in say cell G4 for a particular state and then have all corresponding items returned in a separate cell.

I had pieced something like what's below together but I'm not sure if I'm even on the right path.

```
[=INDEX($B2:$B$250, SMALL(IF(($G$4=$A1:$A$250), MATCH(ROW($A1:$A$250), ROW($A1:$A$250)), ""),ROWS($A$1:A1)))]
```

Any help would go a long way with making me look good to the higher ups :)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSnXV.jpg

**Results of new array**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aP2qt.jpg

Comment: "I'm not sure if I'm even on the right path" - what happens when you use the formula? I suggest you post a screenshot of your data and where your current formula falls down, assuming it does.

Comment: I added a link with a screenshot. When I try California I get the #Value error and when I try the other two states, I get the #N/A error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem with your formula is that the ranges are different sizes which will cause an error. The first range refers to B2:B250, the others start at row 1.

Here is an alternative array formula (because I don't know how to fix yours!) It's longer but does the job.It assumes the results start in I3 and copy the formula down as far as necessary.

```
=IF(ROWS(I$3:I3)<=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$10,$G$4),INDEX($B$1:$B$10,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$10=$G$4,ROW($A$1:$A$10)-ROW($A$1)+1),ROWS(I$3:I3))),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried pasting it into I3 and copying it down. I attached a second screenshot to the original posting of the results.

Would this work when the original data (columns A and B are hidden)? Is it possible to just have the formula in one cell and return multiple values or does it have to be copied down?

Comment: I don't think you can put the results in a single cell without some VBA.

Comment: They can be in multiple cells but I was just trying to avoid having to place the formula in each cell.

Comment: Put it in I3, remember to use Ctrl, Shift and Enter, and then just copy down.

Comment: That's what I forgot to do. thank you so much for the help!